# Can a duplicate column entry be made null based on a condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql

Can a duplicate column entry be made null based on a condition in SQL?

```
Prod  |  service_type   | Units    | Total_prod_quantity
---------------------------------------------------------------
Prod_1     Svc_type_1       20          100
Prod_1     Svc_type_2       50          100
Prod_1     Svc_type_3       30          100
Prod_2     Svc_type_1       25          50
Prod_2     Svc_type_2       25          50
```

When I am trying to calculate the total service attach percentage at a row level, I get the right numbers (20/100 = .2, 50/100 = 0.5). But when I try to calculate the overall service attach percentage at a product level, I should get ( (20+50+30)/100 = 1 and not (20+50+30)/(100+100+100) = 0.3). Is there anyway to make the duplicate column entries null based on a condition as shown below?

```
Prod  |  service_type   | Units    | Total_prod_quantity
---------------------------------------------------------------
Prod_1     Svc_type_1       20          100
Prod_1     Svc_type_2       50          0
Prod_1     Svc_type_3       30          0
Prod_2     Svc_type_1       25          50
Prod_2     Svc_type_2       25          0
```

Comment: If it will always return `1` - why calculate anything at all?

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate like this without changing the table data:

```
select 
    prod,
    sum(units)/max(total_prod_quantity)
from table
group by prod
```